# Both frames showing

Tags: java, jframe

I have application with 2 Jframes. 
JFrame1 is parrent, Jframe2 is a child of Frame1. 
As you can see on IMG2, there is child and parent showing at same frame. 
I have condtion like this

[image]

Frame1 
[image]
Frame
[image: desired output]

Comment: I have condition something like this. 
 if(uspesnePrihlasenie == true) {
                   this.setVisible(false);
                   new inside().setVisible(true);
                                      }

Comment: I just want to show Frame2 without Frame1

Comment: What's the desired output? Please provide a [mcve]. Without code, we've no idea what you've tried.

Comment: added image to the description.

Comment: If you want only 1 visible frame, then don't use a second frame at all. Replace the content in its contentPane instead.